# Deprecation Errors When Trying to Run an Old Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have an older Laravel project (v. 5.7.9) that I cloned from my GitHub onto a new machine. The new machine was running PHP 8.1.11, but when trying to `composer update` the old project errored out, requiring me to use 7.1.

I switched to Composer 1 and downgraded the PHP on my machine to 7.1 so I could `composer update` (it wouldn't run otherwise).

When I try to `composer update` now, I get a PGP Fatal error related to memory size and when I try to run the project in my browser, I am met with a boatload of error messages:

> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
> on line 1823
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetGet($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
> on line 1834
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetSet($key, $value) should either
> be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed
> $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be
> used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
> on line 1846
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetUnset($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
> on line 1861
>
> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::count()
> should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
> on line 1802
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Support\Collection::getIterator() should either be
> compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
> on line 1781
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Support\Collection::jsonSerialize() should either be
> compatible with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize(): mixed, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
> on line 1750
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 1209
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 1220
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either
> be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed
> $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be
> used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 1232
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 1245
>
> Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 838
>
> Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 912
>
> Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 838
>
> Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php
> on line 912
>
> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::count()
> should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php
> on line 347
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::getIterator() should either be
> compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php
> on line 337
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Http\Request::offsetExists($offset) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php
> on line 621
>
> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Http\Request::offsetGet($offset)
> should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed
> $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be
> used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php
> on line 635
>
> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Http\Request::offsetSet($offset,
> $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed
> $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
> attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php
> on line 647
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Http\Request::offsetUnset($offset) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php
> on line 658
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::getIterator() should
> either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator():
> Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used
> to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ParameterBag.php
> on line 220
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::count() should either
> be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ParameterBag.php
> on line 230
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag::getIterator() should
> either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator():
> Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used
> to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/HeaderBag.php
> on line 280
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag::count() should either be
> compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/HeaderBag.php
> on line 290
>
> Deprecated: auto_detect_line_endings is deprecated in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Loader.php
> on line 162
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php
> on line 141
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php
> on line 152
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value):
> void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to
> temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php
> on line 164
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be
> compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php
> on line 175
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::getIterator() should either be
> compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php
> on line 565
>
> Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::count()
> should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php
> on line 636
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FileTypeFilterIterator::accept()
> should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or
> the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily
> suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FileTypeFilterIterator.php
> on line 42
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren()
> should either be compatible with
> RecursiveDirectoryIterator::getChildren(): RecursiveDirectoryIterator,
> or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to
> temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php
> on line 81
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::rewind()
> should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::rewind(): void,
> or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to
> temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php
> on line 109
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::current()
> should either be compatible with FilesystemIterator::current():
> SplFileInfo|FilesystemIterator|string, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
> attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/RecursiveDirectoryIterator.php
> on line 61
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::accept()
> should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or
> the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily
> suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php
> on line 55
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::hasChildren()
> should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::hasChildren():
> bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to
> temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php
> on line 71
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator::getChildren()
> should either be compatible with RecursiveIterator::getChildren():
> ?RecursiveIterator, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should
> be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator.php
> on line 76
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\FilenameFilterIterator::accept()
> should either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or
> the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily
> suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/FilenameFilterIterator.php
> on line 28
>
> Deprecated: Return type of
> Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\PathFilterIterator::accept() should
> either be compatible with FilterIterator::accept(): bool, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> /Users/[myusername]/Sites/[projectname]/vendor/symfony/finder/Iterator/PathFilterIterator.php
> on line 27

Is it possible to resurrect this old project on a new machine?

Comment: Check this library https://github.com/rectorphp/rector

Comment: If you simply want to run that project, why do you need `composer update` ?

Comment: Sorry - I meant alter it (not just run it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be easier to upgrade it to a newer version of laravel, you can use 'laravel shift' which is a website you pay for.

or

you could do it by hand. i did that recently and it worked and was fairly easy.

step 1. install a new repo using  laravel 9

step 2. copy in the routes, controllers, views, models and what ever else is in the app, resources, public and main folders

step 3. recreate the .env, composer.json and package.json files and run composer install, npm run dev

you may find errors which you can solve, but if you know a bit, it is easier than trying to mangle old versions of php to work.

good luck

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I will attempt this and keep you posted.

Comment: One strange thing that has occurred is when I try to run the site migrated by hand over to Laravel 9, I get an error message that says a class is not found. So I change the reference to include the /Models directory and try running the site again and I'm hit with a 500 error. But not your typical 500 error with a message—this produces no other output or error log entry. Just "This page isn't working." I changed the permissions for the Storage and Logs folders and the laravel.log file but the error remains. Did you run into something like this as well?

Comment: i wrote a blog at

https://allotmentandy.github.io/blog/2022-10-10-Upgrading-Laravel-7-to-Laravel-9/

about the error for the class not found. 


Have you done the chmod -R 755 storage